# The energy released from burning one gallon of gasoline

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

How can I get this information from *Mathematica* or Wolfram|Alpha?

Comment: Google search is better for finding what you are looking for. I get 1.3*^8 Joules from the 2nd hit from a search on "energy from burning 1 gallon gasoline"

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> `gasoline heat of combustion * density` results in:

```
Quantity[32.7, "Kilojoules"/"Centimeters"^3]
```

To get energy per gallon:

```
UnitConvert[%, "Joules"/"Gallons"]

(* Quantity[1.23782965*^8, "Joules"/"Gallons"] *)
```